# What is the significance of Ruby Rhod appearing on the menu screen of "The Fifth Element" video game?

Tags: video-games, the-fifth-element

In *[The Fifth Element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fifth_Element_(video_game))* (1998 PS1 video game), why is Ruby Rhod on the menu screen? Why does he run away and where is he going? What even is the place where Ruby Rhod shows up?

Video of Ruby Rhod (relevant part starts at 02:42):

##### What is the significance of Ruby Rhod appearing on the menu screen of "The Fifth Element" video game?

Comment: Relevant [meta] post about this question's closure: [Why was the "Ruby Rhod appearing on the menu screen of The Fifth Element" question closed as "needs more focus"?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13909/7957)

Answer (score 7):

The 'Mission Intro Menu' is described in the [game's manual](https://vimm.net/manual/?p=details&id=1059) thusly;

> Ruby Rhod, the best DJ in the universe, will go to the extreme to put
> on the most incredible performance for his 50 billion listeners. **He is
> here to tell your story...**

It would appear that he's functioning as the narrator. That is to say, the story that you're playing is the story that he's relating to his audience after the fact.